Ginzburg-Landau Theory and the Bose-Einstein Condensate
In Introduction to Superconductivity by Tinkham, it's said that the Ginzburg-Landau Theory of superconductivity was developed in 1950, seven years before the BCS theory. They introduced the pseudo-wave function $\Psi$ as the order parameter and they used the free energy method etc. But after some pages it's said that this wave function is associated to the Bose-Einstein condensate where cooper pairs behave like bosons.
If the BCS theory (which introduced the concept of the Cooper pair) was published after the Ginzburg-Landau theory, what is the link between the wave function $\Psi$ and the Bose-Einstein condensate?

One version of superconductivity is that of "pre-formed pairs" where a pair of fermions combine to form a new particle which has integer spin and  which then  Bose-condenses.  The Bose condensate can  be described by a Gross-Pitaevesky equation which follows from the Landau-Ginzburg functional. In that case the $\Psi$ in that equation can be thought of  a single particle wavefunction with $|\Psi|^2$ as the particle density.
Despite simplistic explanantions in introductory texts, this is  not what happens in the BCS theory where the motion of pairs of fermions simply becomes correlated. The resulting "Cooper-pairs" are not simply bound states of two fermions. The LG functional is still useful, but it is not really describing a Bose condesate, and in particlar $|\Psi|^2$ is not the particle density -- so the answer to you question is really that there is not a straightforward connection.
In cold-atom systems it is possible to use a magnetic field to tune the strength of the interaction between pairs of fermionic atoms (Potassium-40) and so pass from a strongly interacting  pre-formed pair situation to  the weakly coupled BCS state

but the wave function describing the bose-einsten condensate is the same wave function introduced by Ginzburg - Landau ?

@ user424762. The quantity $\Psi$ in the LG fuctional is the order-parameter $\langle \psi\psi\rangle$  which governs the gap above the Feri surface. It  is not a wavefunction.
